# authentication flow in react native drawer

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm new in react native. I'm working on a practice project but I was stuck to understand the concept of the authentication flow.
On my app One is admin having these screens AddUser, all data, allUser, uploadfile, and second is User having this screen allData.

But how I can add auth flow?
On the opening of app, I want to display **Login** after I mention above about admin and user.

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import AllData from '../components/alldata';
import AllUsers from '../components/alluser';
import AddUser from '../components/adduser';
import Login from '../components/login';
import UploadFile from '../components/uploadfile';



const RootNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
    Login:{screen:Login},
    Add_User:{
        screen: AddUser,
        navigationOptions:{
            drawerLabel: 'Add User',
        }
    },
    Data:{screen: AllData},
    Users:{screen: AllUsers},
    Uploader:{screen: UploadFile}
});


export default createAppContainer(RootNavigation);
```

that's my drawer.

Comment: you tagged "authentication-flows"; "authentication-flows" is a framework that covers all flows that authentication-server that is based on Spring-Security needs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [medium auth flow tutorial](https://medium.com/@mike.almpertis/react-navigation-5-0-authentication-flow-using-context-hooks-and-aws-cognito-3f7d50df7921), I'm using this to handle multiple user roles in my mobile app and it works flawlessly.

You don't need to use AWS, just replace it with you backend server auth api.

To handle multiple roles, alter AppNavigator return like this:

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        {userToken ?
            isAdmin
                <AdminModule />
            :   
                <UserModule />      
        :               
            <AuthModule />
        }
    </NavigationContainer>
);
```

All of these Modules are just StackNavigators, or BottomTabNavigators or both combined, it's up to you.

Use react hooks to get token or admin/user from auth:

```
const { userToken, isAdmin } = useAuthState();
```

Alter the reducer to handle multiple roles:

```
case 'SIGN_IN':
  return {
    ...prevState,
    isSignout: false,
    userToken: action.token,
    isAdmin: false,
  };
case 'SIGN_IN_ADMIN':
  return {
    ...prevState,
    isSignout: false,
    userToken: action.token,
    isAdmin: true,
  };
```

Also alter the AuthProvider to handle multiple roles (these are default values):

```
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(AuthReducer, {
    isLoading: true,
    isSignout: false,
    userToken: null,
    isAdmin: false,
  });
```

After successful login dispatch desired type according to role:

```
dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN_ADMIN', token: global.token });
```

The reason this works, is you need to wrap all your application in the AuthProvider like this:

```
<AuthProvider>
    <AppNavigator />
</AuthProvider>
```

Then everytime you dispatch() something, the app re-renders UI according to the role you dispatched.

I spent days on this, hope you will get it done faster with this help.